# The right way to convert GeoJSON to DXF using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, geojson, vector, dxf

I have a problem exporting GeoJSON to vector format.

I downloaded GeoJSON of highway objects from OSM, opened it in QGIS, and then saved it as DXF.

The problem is when I open it in CorelDraw, road shape consists of thousands of parts and nodes and I don't know how to convert it into single curve (CorelDraw just hangs-up)

I need a single closed curve with minimum nodes, may be there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Could you provide some more details about your workflow? Where did you get the data (could you link to it)? How did you export it to DXF?

Comment: I've used https://overpass-turbo.eu/ service, ran a query there highway=tertiary and highway=primary and so on... then exported resulting data as geoJSON. After that i opened this file in QGIS and exported as DXF, Then i imported it in CorelDraw

Comment: In QGIS i did projects -> import / export / export project as DXF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your workflow and found out that CorelDraw would import the same amount of lines and nodes in my test when importing a DXF file generated by QGIS. Below is the description of how I did it :

I have installed the OSM downloader plug-in which is available from the QGIS repository.

[image]

Using the tool, I downloaded some roads from OSM by selecting an area from the view.

[image]

The download took only a few seconds as the are is small.

[image]

I selected all the layers to be added into my layers list to inspect and choose what I need and what had to be removed.

[image]

The roads have been added (I changed the color to red for easy viewing).

[image]

I opened the attribute table for the road layer and noticed that many features (line segments) had the same name. Although some features where boundaries but it is well documented so they can be filtered.

[image]

In order to merge the lines with the same name, I need to use the "**Dissolve**" geoprocessing tool from the vector menu (see image below).

[image]

I dissolved using the field name "Name". Here I have the choice to export directly the data into another format.

[image]

[image]

I tried DXF but run into an issue so I chose GeoJSON as the output format.

[image]

The output after the processing was added since I had selected "Open output file after running algorithm"

[image]

I right clicked on the layer name and chose the option "Export ---> Save Layer As" and chose DXF as a format.

[image]

[image]

I opened the DXF file in CorelDraw 2019 and put the window side by side with QGIS. I chose a feature ans selected it in both CorelDraw and QGIS, I can notice that the features have the same number of nodes and it is the same entity that is being selected in both software.

[image]

Just a final note, I would suggest you export only the portion you need to use in CorelDraw rather than the entire file. That might slowdown CorelDraw's performance or any other software if the file is huge.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed explanation!

Comment: @Alexmind, if the explanation is what you were looking for, kindly mark it as "Right Answer". Thanks.