# How do you merge multiple polyline features into one contiguous feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, features, polyline-creation

I created a shapefile from public GIS data, that I wanted to display in Google Maps for presentation purposes. The original .shp used small line segments for roads. Maybe a picture will make sense:

[image]

As you can see, the feature class is made up on 164 little line segments. I want it to be one contiguous feature, so that when I import into Google Maps, it doesn't list every separate line segment. How can I do that? [image]

For the record, I'm using QGIS 3.6.1 with GRASS 7.6.1.

Comment: I think you might be after Dissolve https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/dissolve.html?highlight=dissolve to merge your paths into a single polyline.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Dissolve to under the Vector ---- > Geoprocessing Tools ---- > Dissolve

[image]

Take a look at the answer in this thread which explains in details how you can dissolve lines based on an attribute.

[The right way to convert GeoJSON to DXF using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351012/the-right-way-to-convert-geojson-to-dxf-using-qgis)